# Want to install python 3.5.1 on Redhat 6.5? Will it break dependencies?

Tags: python, dependencies, redhat

I want to replace python 2.7 by 3.5 on Redhat 6.5. Will it cause any problem?

Comment: Depends on your definition of problem ...

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is not to replace but install your new python besides old one. just download and compile new python and at last run `make altinstall`. this will keep your main python and new one together.

Check [This link](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#building-python) for complete description: